# How to get the accounts listed in a twitter public list?

Tags: r, twitter

I'm looking for a solution about collecting in R all the accounts (users screennames) of a member's public list on Twitter.

The twitteR package doesn't help here (actually, I hope). It doesn't give any tool to explore twitter public lists (something I didn't know until today, but somehting I've learned on the dedicaced mailing list)

So I suppose I need to use something like RCurl. But I've no idea how. And it seems (for google) that nobody has never tryed it (since the API 1.1).

The list I try to get is (for example) : [AssembleeNat/deputes](https://twitter.com/AssembleeNat/les-d%C3%A9put%C3%A9s/members)

And I precise that I'm actually correctly authentificated in R with my own twitter account :

```
require(twitteR)
requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "xxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxx"
Cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=requestURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL, 
                         authURL=authURL)
Cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl") )
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
  > TRUE
accounts_list <- ... ?
```

Any help would be appreciated ! :)

Comment: check out the answer I had to a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063597/obtaining-twitter-screen-names-from-a-twitter-list