# Obtaining twitter screen names from a twitter list

Tags: r, twitter

I am keen to get a list of usernames and fullnames names from a specific twitter list using R. 
 I could not see a function in any package but this code works

```
library(XML)
library(httr)


url.name <- "https://twitter.com/TwitterUK/lists/premier-league-players/members"
url.get=GET(url.name)
url.content=content(url.get, as="text")
pagehtml <- htmlParse(url.content)

screenNames <-xpathSApply(pagehtml, '//*/span[@class="username js-action-profile-name"]',xmlValue)
realName <- xpathSApply(pagehtml, '//*/strong[@class="fullname js-action-profile-name"]',xmlValue)
```

However, it only provides the first 20 values (? what appears on screen) whilst the list is much longer

If there is an rvest solution, this would also be welcome

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work with R and twitter, you should take a look at the `twitteR` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf). It doesn't have a function to retrieve the information you want, but we can take advantage of its internal functions to use OAuth, and then send the [correct API call](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members). The advantage of using API calls is that you don't rely on parsing the HTML page, you're actually doing what developers are supposed to do.

The code below assumes you have already authenticated using `setup_twitter_oauth()`, you can find tutorials on this easily, since it's the package basics. Once authenticated, let's load the packages we need:

```
library(rjson)
library(httr)
# library(twitteR) Should have been loaded already of course
```

Now to do the API call, we'll use `POST`. The URL has a `slug` parameter which is the twitter list name, and a `owner_screen_name` parameter which is the Twitter Account owner of the list. We'll use internal `twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()` to authenticate the call.

```
twlist <- "premier-league-players"
twowner <- "TwitterUK"
api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=",
           twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&count=5000")
response <- POST(api.url, config(token=twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()))
#Count = 5000 is the number of names per result page,
#        which for this case simplifies things to one page.
```

This returns a JSON response which we can read using `fromJSON`:

```
response.list <- fromJSON(content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Now, we have a list where each element is the Twitter data of one Twitter-list member. To extract their names and user_names:

```
users.names <- sapply(response.list$users, function(i) i$name)
users.screennames <- sapply(response.list$users, function(i) i$screen_name)
```

Which are:

```
> head(users.names)
[1] "Peter Crouch"         "barry bannan"         "Jose Leonardo Ulloa "
    "Paul McShane"         "nacho monreal"        "James Ward-Prowse"
> head(users.screennames)
[1] "petercrouch"   "bazzabannan25" "Ciclone1923"   "pmacca15"
    "_nachomonreal" "Prowsey16"
```

Now the best part of this code is that it opens up pretty much the entire twitter API from R, as an already authenticated request. You can check the response list and sublists for all the available information on each query.

Comment: Thanks so much for the excellently-commented answer. As you say, it opens up a lot of info. What is the best way to  find out what elements are available in the lists and sublists  e.g name, screen_name

Comment: I was using `names(response.list)` to check what is in that, and then `names(response.list$users)`, and so on. `str(response.list)` also works, but may be difficult to understand if there are too many nested lists.

Comment: Yes  `str(response.list)` is a handful. However, I get `NULL` response to `names(response.list$users)`

Comment: That was my mistake. `$users` is an unnamed list, but each user is a named list, so it should be `response.list$users[[1]]`. The number of the user does not matter since all users have the same type of data. In fact, you can transform that into a data frame with (untested code) `do.call(rbind, response.list$users)`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Molx does not seem to work any more. The problem seems to lie in

```
api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=",
           twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&count=5000")
```

This URL does not seem valid, for any twlist or twowner that I tried.
EDIT : the problem comes from the authentication I think as I get

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

I think I'm authenticated with this

```
## Twitter authentication, 
consumer_key = "xxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xxxxx"
access_secret = "xxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,
access_secret)
```

Where does the problem come from ?

EDIT : When I enter `get_oauth_sig()` I get the result below

```
> twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()
<Token>
NULL
<oauth_app> twitter
  key:    XXXXXXX
  secret: <hidden>
<credentials> oauth_token, oauth_token_secret
---
```

Is this normal ?

The solution from Molx does not seem to work any more. The problem seems to lie in

```
api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=",
           twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&count=5000")
```

This URL does not seem valid, for any twlist or twowner that I tried.
EDIT : the problem comes from the authentication I think as I get

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

I think I'm authenticated with this

```
## Twitter authentication, 
consumer_key = "xxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xxxxx"
access_secret = "xxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,
access_secret)
```

Where does the problem come from ?

EDIT : When I enter `get_oauth_sig()` I get the result below

```
> twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()
<Token>
NULL
<oauth_app> twitter
  key:    XXXXXXX
  secret: <hidden>
<credentials> oauth_token, oauth_token_secret
---
```

Is this normal ?

EDIT : I solve the problem by replacing POST by GET

```
library(rjson)
library(twitteR)
consumer_key = "xxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xxxxx"
access_secret = "xxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,
access_secret)
https://twitter.com/ivalerio/lists/justice?lang=fr
twlist <- "d-put-s-2017-2022"
twowner <- "ivalerio"
api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=",
           twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&count=5000")
response <- GET(api.url, config(token=twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()))
#Count = 5000 is the number of names per result page,
#        which for this case simplifies things to one page.
# This returns a JSON response which we can read using fromJSON:
response.list <- fromJSON(content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8"))
# Now, we have a list where each element is the Twitter data of one Twitter-list member. To extract their names and user_names:
users.names <- sapply(response.list$users, function(i) i$name)
users.screennames <- sapply(response.list$users, function(i) i$screen_name)
# Which are:
head(users.names)
```