# "This method requires a GET or HEAD" error using twitteR, rjson, httr

Tags: authentication, twitter, httr, rjson

I am following code provided on a [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063597/obtaining-twitter-screen-names-from-a-twitter-list) from several years ago, but I am getting an error when I run the 'fromJSON' command, "Code 86, This method requires a GET or HEAD". I am trying to get a list of usernames from a public Twitter list (all NHL players).

Here is the code

```
# load packages
library("twitteR")
library("rjson")
library("httr")

consumer_key <- "XXX"
consumer_secret <- "XXX"
access_token <- "XXX"
access_secret <- "XXX"
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

twlist <- "nhl-players"
twowner <- "NHL"
api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=",
              twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&count=500")
response <- POST(api.url, config(token=twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()))
fromJSON(content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `"&NHL"` part of  `api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=",
              twlist, "&NHL=", twowner, "&count=500")` is right?  Shouldn't it rather say `&owner_screen_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it. There is a little typo in your `api.url` object. It's not "&NHL="(which is the actual value), it's "&owner_screen_name=" (which is the name of the paramater that you want to pass). Plus you need to use a GET request.

```
 api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=", twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&count=500")
 response <- GET(api.url, config(token=twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply... yes, you are correct that is a typo... I fixed it, and am having a different problem now, so I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: I apologize... this was something I had tried earlier, but since I get an error either way, I wasn't sure whether it should be "&NHL" or "&owner_screen_name"

Comment: Yes! so i need GET rather than POST... i am a n00b, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For someone who was struggeling like me. This is the code that works now:

```
api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=", twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&cursor=-1&count=1000")
response <- GET(api.url, config(token = twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()))
```

As you can see you need to add `&cursor=-1`