# Extracting tweets from a list using R

Tags: r, twitter

I am using R to extract tweets of congress members. I know I can use the get_timeline function from rtweet package to extract tweets of multiple people within one code. However, I am looking for a faster and more efficient way to deal with hundreds of users. I have created a list of all congress members that I need for my research on Twitter and it includes more than 600 users. Is there a way I can write a code and use the "list of congress members" instead of individual congress member IDs?

Comment: Hey Golnar! I wanna help you out but it would be helpful if you could show some of the code that you have tried and what is and isn't working for ya

Comment: Thank you ! I am using the codes explained in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065409/9518016.

The problem comes from response.list <- fromJSON (content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")). 
I get the following error :
Error in fromJSON(content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")) : 
  no data to parse